# TCP transfer duration

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have two applications communicating via TCP sockets. First one receives and the second sends.

```
First app:
start=clock();
recv();
end=clock();
```

when i run the application, (end-start) is 150-200 msecs.(always)

Second app:

```
while (!stop) {
    start=clock();
    prepare_message();
    send();
    end=clock();
}
```

when i run the application, (end-start) is 0.00 msecs. (always)

Message payload is nearly 200-300 bytes and the ping duration is <1ms. So, why does the receiver wait for 200ms while the sender does not wait?
So how can i describe the 200msecs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender is sending the message whenever it is ready. The receiver has to wait for the message, and this is where this extra time may come from. How do you ensure that recv() is called after the message has been send? If you don't, then recv() is most likely waiting for input, while the sender hasn't yet reach this part of the code.

Another thing is that depending on the methods you are using, the sender only saves the message in a buffer, as TCP can wait for more data to combine it in a single package. You should use [TCP_NODELAY](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=tcp) option to avoid that.

Comment: thanks, i will try tcp_nodelay.i have edited my pseudo. it loops in 'while' so it is either sending or preparing the message while receiver is waiting for a new message.